# Silverstripe who to submit Form into Formextension

Tags: forms, silverstripe

I use silverstripe 4.0.3

I made and extension for a Form. I adde the extension via yml to PageController. This is my Extension Class:

```
class NewsLetterFormExtension extends DataExtension
{
 private static $allowed_actions = [
    'NewsletterForm'
];

public function NewsletterForm()
{
    $form = Form::create(
        null,
        __Function__,
        FieldList::create(
            LiteralField::create('Newsletter','<h2>NewsLetter</h2>')
                ->addExtraClass(''),
            LiteralField::create('NLContent','<p>Erfaharen sie regelmäßig was uns beschäftigt</p>')
                ->addExtraClass(''),
            TextField::create('FirstName')
                ->setAttribute('palceholder', 'Vorname')
                ->addExtraClass(''),
            TextField::create('Surname')
                ->setAttribute('palceholder', 'Nachname')
                ->addExtraClass(''),
            EmailField::create('Email')
                ->setAttribute('palceholder', 'E-mail Adresse')
                ->addExtraClass('')
        ),
        FieldList::create(
            FormAction::create('handleNewsletter', 'Senden')
                ->addExtraClass('btn btn-primary btn-sm')
        ),
        RequiredFields::create('FirstName','Surname', 'Email')
    );
    return $form;
 }

 public function handleNewsletter($data, $form)
 {
    $Newsletter = Newsletter::create();
    $form->saveInto($Newsletter);
    try {
        $Newsletter->write();
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        return $e->getMessage();
    }

    $form->sessionMessage('Danke für die Newsletter Anmeldung', 'good');

    return $this->redirectBack();
 }
}
```

As Controller i am passing null. What would be the correct controller to submit it into the extension? Or is it even possible to do so?

I tried to pass it PageController and handle submission there. But I can not get it to work.

An actually i'd would like to submit into it self so that i can add it to multible page types.

Answer (score 1):

You could try extending the **Form** class. This isn't tested but should work :)

**NewsletterForm.php**

```
class NewsletterForm extends Form {

    function __construct($controller, $name) {

        $form_name = $name;


        $fields = FieldList::create(
            LiteralField::create('Newsletter','<h2>NewsLetter</h2>')
                ->addExtraClass(''),
            LiteralField::create('NLContent','<p>Erfaharen sie regelmäßig was uns beschäftigt</p>')
                ->addExtraClass(''),
            TextField::create('FirstName')
                ->setAttribute('palceholder', 'Vorname')
                ->addExtraClass(''),
            TextField::create('Surname')
                ->setAttribute('palceholder', 'Nachname')
                ->addExtraClass(''),
            EmailField::create('Email')
                ->setAttribute('palceholder', 'E-mail Adresse')
                ->addExtraClass('')
        );


        $actions = FieldList::create(
            FormAction::create('handleNewsletter', 'Senden')
                ->addExtraClass('btn btn-primary btn-sm')
        );

        $validator = RequiredFields::create('FirstName','Surname', 'Email')

        parent::__construct($controller, $form_name, $fields, $actions, $validator);
    }



    handleNewsletter($data, $form) {
        $Newsletter = Newsletter::create();
        $form->saveInto($Newsletter);
        try {
            $Newsletter->write();
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            return $e->getMessage();
        }

        $form->sessionMessage('Danke für die Newsletter Anmeldung', 'good');

        return $this->redirectBack();
    }

}
```

**NewsletterFormExtension.php**

```
class NewsLetterFormExtension extends DataExtension {
    private static $allowed_actions = [
        'NewsletterForm'
    ];

    public function NewsletterForm() {
        $f = new NewsletterForm($this, 'NewsletterForm');
        return $f;
    }
}
```